# How to create jrxml for sub reporting

Tags: jasper-reports, subreport

I want create a complex *jrxml* file to create PDF.

I want to put another *jrxml* in my *jrxml* file.

So.. my question is how to put one *jrxml* to another *jrxml*

My *jrxml* files are: *salesreport.jrxml*, *financialreport.jrxml* and *report.jrxml*

I want to put *salesreport.jrxml* and *financialreport.jrxml* to *report.jrxml*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually you develop reports with [iReport](http://jasperforge.org/projects/ireport).

iReport has facilities for including subreports within reports (by dragging the subreport icon onto the master report page).

Note that JasperReports uses *absolute paths* for file references. I would recommend you set up parameters to your reports as follows:

```
$P{ROOT_DIR}
$P{SUBREPORT_DIR}
```

Give `$P{SUBREPORT_DIR}` a default value of `$P{ROOT_DIR} + "subreports/"`.

At that point, you can pass the *absolute path* as `$P{ROOT_DIR}` into your report and then the subreports will be stored in a subdirectory called `subreports`, which is located in `$P{ROOT_DIR}`.

Comment: Creating a subreport seems like overkill when you only want to include a header in multiple PDF reports.  Is there nothing analogous to  an include statement in the jrxml you could use to incorporate one blurb of jrxml into mutiple other documents?

Answer (score 0):

Or use the JasperCompileManager class from within the master jrxml file to dynamically compile it.

```
<subreportExpression><![CDATA[JasperCompileManager.compileReport($P{SUBREPORT_DIR}+"/myFile.jrxml")]]></subreportExpression>
```